# state of material UI multi select doesn't update properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multi-select

state of multiple select in material-ui doesn't work properly.

for example: when I select each item of menu for first time, state doesn't change and is like this: []

then by selecting the second item state change to this: ['item'].

these are my codes on codesandbox, please take a look:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fovpo?fontsize=14

Comment: Provide more detailed description of your problem, I've took a look into sandbox and I couldn't understand what is working wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in your code, you are not talking about the Material UI state but your component state. And for your state I can reassure you that everything works properly.

You can check your components state via doing your console logging (`console.log(personName);`) directly before your components return statement (not in your handleChange function). You will see that - with every change of your selection - your component will re-render with the current state. And this is what you see as well in the actual render.

Why does it not work currently?:
Since you are logging the state in your handleChange function you might not see the just changed current state until your component rerendered with the new state.

Answer (score 1):

Your state updates properly. Take a look at this function:

```
  function handleChange(event) {
    setPersonName(event.target.value);
    console.log(personName);
  }
```

setPersonName is an async function. So when you're printing personName, it probably hasn't been updated yet, that's why it's printing the last personName.

If you want to do something based on the value, either use event.target.value, or use useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(personName);
    //do something here with personName
  }, [personName]);
```

You can refer to this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-1ojn2) demo